# Wordpress widget modifications don't apply

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I created my own WordPress plugin with widgets, and my problem is when I make modifications in my widgetname_widget.php half of the modification are not applied.

My code:

```
class Blocs_Home_HS_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct('blocshomehswidget', 'Blocs Home (version mobile)', array('description' => 'Gestion du contenu des blocs de la page d\'accueil version mobile'));
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance) {

        $strReturn = disposition_blocs_home_handheld(array('sport_title' => $instance['sport_title'], 'sport_content' => $instance['sport_content'], 'sante_title' => $instance['sante_title'], 'sante_content' => $instance['sante_content'], 'be_title' => $instance['be_title'], 'be_content' => $instance['be_content'], 'recup_title' => $instance['recup_title'], 'recup_content' => $instance['recup_content']));

        echo $strReturn;
    }

    public function form($instance) {

        $sport_title = isset($instance['sport_title']) ? $instance['sport_title'] : '';
        $sport_content = isset($instance['sport_content']) ? $instance['sport_content'] : '';
        $sante_title = isset($instance['sante_title']) ? $instance['sante_title'] : '';
        $sante_content = isset($instance['sante_content']) ? $instance['sante_content'] : '';
        $be_title = isset($instance['be_title']) ? $instance['be_title'] : '';
        $be_content = isset($instance['be_content']) ? $instance['be_content'] : '';
        $recup_title = isset($instance['recup_title']) ? $instance['recup_title'] : '';
        $recup_content = isset($instance['recup_content']) ? $instance['recup_content'] : '';

        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sport_title');?>"><?php _e('Titre du bloc sport : ');?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sport_title');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sport_title');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $sport_title;?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sport_content');?>"><?php _e('Contenu du bloc sport (max 56 caratères par ligne, max 280 au total) : ');?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sport_content');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sport_content');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $sport_content;?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sante_title');?>"><?php _e('Titre du bloc santé :');?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sante_title');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sante_title');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $sante_title;?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sante_content');?>"><?php _e('Contenu du bloc santé (max 56 caratères par ligne, max 280 au total) :');?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sante_content');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sante_content');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $sante_content;?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('be_title');?>"><?php _e('Titre du bloc bien-être :');?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('be_title');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('be_title');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $be_title;?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('be_content');?>"><?php _e('Contenu du bloc bien-être (max 56 caratères par ligne, max 280 au total) :');?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('be_content');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('be_content');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $be_content;?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('recup_title');?>"><?php _e('Titre du bloc récupération :');?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('recup_title');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('recup_title');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $recup_title;?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('recup_content');?>"><?php _e('Contenu du bloc récupération (max 56 caratères par ligne, max 280 au total) :');?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('recup_content');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('recup_content');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $recup_content;?>" />
        </p>

        <?php
    }

    public function random_pos_handheld($param) {

        $toReturn = array();
        $tempId = '';
        $tempTitle = '';
        $tempContent = '';
        $logRand = array();

        for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {

            $random = rand(0, 3);

            if(in_array($random, $logRand)) {

                $i--;
            }
            else {

                array_push($logRand, $random);

                switch($random) {

                    case 0:
                        $tempId = 'sport';
                        $tempTitle = $param['sport_title'];
                        $tempContent = $param['sport_content'];
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        $tempId = 'sante';
                        $tempTitle = $param['sante_title'];
                        $tempContent = $param['sante_content'];
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        $tempId = 'be';
                        $tempTitle = $param['be_title'];
                        $tempContent = $param['be_content'];
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        $tempId = 'recup';
                        $tempTitle = $param['recup_title'];
                        $tempContent = $param['recup_content'];
                        break;

                    default:
                        
                }

                $toReturn[$i] = array(
                                    'id' => $tempId,
                                    'bloc' => $i,
                                    'title' => $tempTitle,
                                    'content' => $tempContent
                                    );
            }
        }  

        return $toReturn;
    }

    public function disposition_blocs_home_handheld($param) {

        $result = random_pos_handheld($param);

        $strReturn = '';

        foreach($result as $elt) {

            $strReturn .= '<div class="pos_absolute bloc_' .  $elt['id'] . '_hs bloc_' . $elt['bloc'] . '">
                            <img src="wp-content/themes/pulsdesign/images/bloc_' . $elt['id'] . '_hs.jpg" class="pos_absolute float_right img_bloc_home" />
                            <img src="wp-content/themes/pulsdesign/images/segment_bloc_hs_home.png" class="pos_absolute segment_bloc_hs_home" />
                            <p class="pos_absolute bloc_p_title_hs fsize4p4 p_blanc">' . $elt['title'] . '</p>
                            <p class="pos_absolute bloc_p_content fsize39 p_blanc">' . $elt['content'] . '</p>
                            <img src="wp-content/themes/pulsdesign/images/bouton_fade.png" class="button_bloc_solutions_hs pos_absolute" />
                            <p class="pos_absolute text_bloc_solutions_hs p_blanc fsize30"><b>Nos solutions</b></p>
                            <a href="/testimonies_' .  $elt['id'] . '">
                                <img src="wp-content/themes/pulsdesign/images/bouton_fade.png" class="button_bloc_temoignage_hs pos_absolute" />
                                <p class="pos_absolute text_bloc_temoignage_hs p_blanc fsize30"><b>Témoignages<br />clients</b></p>
                            </a>
                            <img src="wp-content/themes/pulsdesign/images/bouton_fade.png" class="button_bloc_sp_articles_hs pos_absolute" />
                            <p class="pos_absolute text_bloc_articles_hs p_blanc fsize30"><b>Articles</b></p>
                        </div>';
        }

        return $strReturn;
    }
}
```

When I modify the functions `widget()`, `form()` and the constructor there's no problem, I reload my page (containing the widget) and the modifications applied.

But when I modify my functions which I created (`random_pos_handheld()` and `disposition_blocs_home_handheld()`), nothing... I tried to reload the page, deactivated and reactivated the plugin, reinstall the last WordPress update... nothing. I think I have to force the reload of `widget_init` but I didn't find anything on Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, big newbie error ...
The solution is ... to call the functions with a `$this->function()` !